# Wildcard search in using Lambda in EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, lambda

I have a search with optional arguments:

```
string id1 = HttpContext.Current.Request["id1"];
string id2 = HttpContext.Current.Request["id2"];

List<Foo> list = context.Foo.Where(l => 
     (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id1) || l.Id1.Contains(id1)) &&
     (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id2) || l.Id2.Contains(id2)))
     .Take(10)
     .ToList());
```

I would like to extend it so that if the string starts with a `*`, the `EndsWith()` - method should be used.

For example, if the first searchstring is `*123`, I want to do a `l.Id1.EndsWith("123")`.

Is there any way to extend my current code, or should I use a different approach?

Comment: I think unless you have a specific reason to use StartsWith or EndsWith then Contains gives you more flexibility

Comment: @Stokedout Well, I'm asking for a reason :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite sure if this is what you were intending, but you can break your logic up by using [`IQueryable(T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx). The query won't be executed until you try to use the collection.

```
public IList<Foo> Search(DbContext<Foo> context, string id1, string id2)
{
    Func<Foo, bool> predicate = l =>
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id1) || l.Id1.Contains(id1))
            && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id2) || l.Id2.Contains(id2)));

    IQueryable<Foo> list = context.Foo.Where(predicate);

    if(id1.StartsWith("*") && id1.Length > 1)
    {
        var searchTerm = id1.Substring(1, id1.Length);
        list = list.Where(l => l.EndsWith(searchTerm));
    }

    return list.Take(10).ToList(); // Execution occurs at this point
}
```

Building up the query:

```
public void BasicSearch(IQueryable<foo> list, string id1, string id2)
{
    Func<Foo, bool> predicate = l =>
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id1) || l.Id1.Contains(id1))
            && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id2) || l.Id2.Contains(id2)));

    list.Where(predicate);
}

public void WildcardSearch(IQueryable<Foo> list, string id1)
{
    if(!id1.StartsWith("*") || id1.Length <= 1) return;

    var searchTerm = id1.Substring(1, id1.Length);
    list.Where(l => l.EndsWith(searchTerm));
}

IQueryable<Foo> list = context.Foo;

BasicSearch(list, id1, id2);
WildcardSearch(list, id1);
var result = list.Take(10); // Execution occurs at this point
```

Comment: Thanks. The issue that I see is that this will end up in quite a lot of if cases. I was hoping to be able to add it to the `predicate` function. But perhaps it's npt a good solution.

Comment: I would just separate out your logic into different methods so you can build up a query. I will edit an example in.